# Using POST information in mySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, post

Simple question, probably takes a rather simple answer, but I haven't found anything online about it. I'm working on an Android app that needs to access a mySQL cloud database. To this end, I'm creating a PHP webservice to interface the two (as well as provide an extra layer of protection for the mySQl credentials). The issue is that I"m using a POST method to send variables to the queries to tell them what operations to do, such as:

```
$db->query("DROP TABLE {$_POST[table]}");
```

The issue is that when I try to send values for something like an INSERT statement, I need to use quotes around the strings. Unfortunately, the UTF-8 encoding turns all the quotes into escaped quotes. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Utf encoding won't escape your quotes - post the code you think is responsible

Comment: Well, something is escaping my quotes. It might be the URL Encoder class I use in the Java HTTP Request class I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use stripslash(%str) to remove the slashes. I don't know where the slashes are coming from, but putting this into code to remove the slashes works.

Comment: The only places the slashes are coming from is [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) which should be turned **off**.